# Record Triggered Flow not triggered when Record Type changes concurrently with a field change

Tags: visual-workflow, record-type, field-update

TLDR: Why does a record-triggered flow not trigger when the Record Type ID is changed Concurrently with the Field Change? (in lightning, when a user clicks "edit record type" then edits the triggering fields on the popup before clicking save)

Here's the details.

The record-triggered flow:

trigger: contact object, field: Role__c changes to X or Y

*-A record is created or updated*

*-Actions and Related Records selected*

*-Only runs when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements*

decision: Is Role__c = X? or Y?

(both decisions result in the same action -an email- with slightly different text)

action: "emailSimple" (pre-built outside-flow action)

Email text templates created inside the flow -- does not reference a custom email alert. For X, Email1 text sends. For Y, Email2 text sends.

Sends email to a staff email field on the contact. This field does not change.

The email sends fine when a record is created, or when the role field is updated. However, if the Record Type ID and the Role__c field are changed at the same time, it does not trigger this flow. The Record Type and the Role Field can be changed concurrently (a user changes the record type and then can update the fields on that page layout before hitting save -- a typical salesforce lightning function). This does not trigger the flow despite the triggering Role__c field having changed upon save. This doesn't prevent the *identical* workflow from triggering, only the flow.

I've read up on the differences between workflow and flow, as well as record types as triggers for flows (which I guess is not possible according to some research?), and the differences between concurrently updating record type and fields vs just fields. No results that could assist. Any advice is welcome.

Images of the actual flow included below.

[image: Flow elements]

[image: Start configuration]

[image: Start configuration]

[image: Decision node]

[image: Action configuration]

[image: Template]

Comment: welcome to SFSE; please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. In your case, please use [edit] and post relevant screen shots from your Flow

Comment: Please do not put meta commentary in your posts, nor blame "the admin" for closing your post. This site is moderated mostly by the community. Users with a high enough reputation can vote to close posts, as was done here. Moderators can unilaterally close posts, but none of us touched this question before now.